# Google Assistant won't launch my Android Studio app that has been publish

Tags: android, console, launch, voice, assistant

I made an app in android studio in java, I published it to the play store as a production release using google play console. I clicked the box for "Integrate my services with App Actions using Actions on Google" in the Setup->Advanced Settings->Actions on Google. However, the check-box next to it is gray, but checked. It has been published for twenty days. It even has a subscription. However, when I say "hey google, open hands-free gpt" it does not launch my app.

I have searched the internet and found nobody with the same problem. I don't know what to examine or change. My AndroidManifest.xml is as the studio made it from the template.

Thank you in advance for any help. This problem escapes my ability to find a solution.

I have tried changing the name, i have tried various intents, actions and categories in androidmanifest.xml. i have attempted to run the app actions tool, which now crashes. while previously it would just do nothing when i clicked "preview." i have asked chatgpt for assistance. followed it's instructions to no avail.